# How can I import an excel table into latex longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, import

I want to import some data from excel which is in table form (raw from that it not formatted) and I want to import into a longtable with the appropriate formatting (if indeed it can be done in one step) what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I would venture to guess your best bet is to get the Excel data in `.csv` form, and then run an external script (in `Python`, `C`, whatever) that translates it into a `LaTeX` table. As for the formatting, that might be harder, since `.csv` doesn't have a single standard. What sort of formatting do you want to keep (i.e. bold words, centering, color...)?

Comment: Does look like what I need but nothing came up when I did a search?

Comment: @Bazman the problem is that such tools are quite a problem. The linked question lists some tools for `Excel->tabular`, which should not be really different from `Excel->longtable` since `tabular` and `longtable` differ only by the headers.